# Angular detect and insert components

Tags: javascript, angular

### Background

I am trying to create a blog using Angular (5). I am using markdown and storing that data outside the application. It downloads the markdown, parses it into an html string, then binds to the `innerHTML` of a div.

I understand that I am working against the grain, but I would really like to be able to create an elegant solution here.

### Problem

Having the ability to use custom components gives us the ability to do a bunch of stuff with our blog that we won't be able to do otherwise. Signup components, custom widgets, etc. We can do all this and still have the ability to store the content separately outside of the application.

Custom components are not detected from the `innerHTML` string. Which doesn't allow it. It seems like `DynamicComponentLoader` used to provide a solution for this, but not anymore.

### Clarity

I am not trying to render only the html, or only a single component. I want to render the html and all components included.

I also don't care that it's bound to the `innerHTML` property, it just seemed to get me the furthest. I can/will use a `resolver` if that would help.

#### Example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wylp55

As you  can see the hello component renders in the html, but not the component itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why doesn't DynamicComponentLoader work?

Comment: `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated (?)

Comment: where did you see that?  I still see it in the docs https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: I read it in another SO post. After looking at https://stackblitz.com/angular/pednjqlegby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad-banner.component.ts. It seems like it isn't going to solve the problem anyways.

Comment: This post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#answer-34786039

Comment: That's from 2 years ago.... the class was removed, but it's a help article now that just uses different types.  Give the article a look, please.

Comment: I did look at the article, but I was not able to get it to work for my situation. That's how I ended up here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I finally figured this out and did a write up.

Here's the link to the updated stack blitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-html.

I also did a full write up on my company blog. https://www.arka.com/blog/dynamically-generate-angular-components-from-external-html.

Comment: Is there any way to get the input parameters working? I would like to create a widget where I can specify the question and the correct answer.